# Spring profile properties inheritance with single properties file

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I have one `application.yml` file containing multiple spring profiles.
I want to inherit properties from one profile to another.

In this example I want to inherit properties of prod profile into prod1 without writing common properties again in prod1 profile.

```
  server:
    port: 8080

  spring:
    datasource:
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    application:
      name: TestApp

    URL: "https://localhost:8181/Services/IDEA-Client-Partners"
  ---
  spring:
    profiles: dev
  ---
  spring:
    profiles: prod

  URL: https://www.ideaedu.org/Services/IDEA-Client-Partners

  ---
  spring:
    profiles: prod1
```

Comment: Why not having separate properties files per profile with one base properties file with common configuration?

Comment: @Smajl  because i have so many profiles, if i create seperate properties files there will be so many files. thats why i created one file.

Answer (score 1):

properties do already inherit if multiple profiles are activate. E.g. if you activate `prod`, and `prod1` all default < prod < prod1 properties will activate with default, getting overwritten by anything in prod, and prod getting overwritten by anything in prod1.

Given your example,

```
 server:
    port: 8080

  spring:
    datasource:
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    application:
      name: TestApp

    URL: "https://localhost:8181/Services/IDEA-Client-Partners"
  ---
  spring:
    profiles: dev
  ---
  spring:
    profiles: prod

  URL: https://www.ideaedu.org/Services/IDEA-Client-Partners
  prodProperty: test
  ---
  spring:
    profiles: prod1

  URL: https://localhost/
```

And activating all profiles, `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod,prod1`

the following properties will be set,

- port = 8080
- diver-class-name= com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
- name = TestApp
- prodProperty = test
- URL = https://localhost/

In case of conflicting properties e.g. `URL` in this example, the last property read wins i.e. when `prod` and `prod1` are active the last property read will in, `prod1`'s definition in this case.